# @Autowired annotation injects null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to autowire a `CrudRepository` in a DTO class but Spring always injects `null` instead of bean .

My code looks like :

```
package com.exampleRestApp.task;

import com.exampleRestApp.workers.WorkerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


public class TaskDTO {

    private int workerID;
    private String name;
    boolean finished;
    private int taskID;

    @Autowired
    WorkerRepository w; //w==null in this moment

public Task MapToEntity() {
    Task task = new Task();
    task.setName(name);
    task.setFinished(finished);
    task.setTaskID(taskID);
    task.setWorker(w.findOne(task.getTaskID()));
    return task;
}
```

And my WorkerRepo :

```
package com.exampleRestApp.workers;

import java.util.List;
public interface WorkerRepository extends CrudRepository<Worker,Integer> {
  List<Worker> findBySurname(String surname);
  List<Worker>findAllByOrderByNameAsc();
}
```

Comment: When do you mean it is null? `this moment` refers to non-executable code..

Comment: You're not even showing how you're using `TaskDTO`, but it looks like it's just a POJO you're instantiating via `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to annotate your WorkerRepository with `@Repository` or `@Service` spring annotations

```
@Repository
public interface WorkerRepository extends CrudRepository<Worker,Integer>
```

Comment: @neir45 , could you post how you are injecting the `TaskDTO` from the service that calls the `MapToEntity()` method ? Cause `TaskDTO` as well doesn't look like a proper spring bean

Comment: @Override
       public void saveTask(TaskDTO task) {
           repo.save(task.MapToEntity());

         }

Comment: please update your answer with the proper code, not in the comments. Also what you posted confirms my suggestion , that `TaskDTO` isnt a spring bean , you are simple passing it with `new`

Comment: annotate you TaskDTO to

Comment: because I want to Autowire repo not taskDTO

Comment: That will not be autowired but you have to tell the spring that it is also a bean otherwise spring DI will ignore it.

Comment: add @Service service annotation on it